# Twitter Bootstrap collapsed navbar button opens new tab instead of the menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can't find this problem anywhere else as a bug, so looking for some help.

When http://seontario.org/ is at lower breakpoint the menu button shows. That button should open the collapsed menu below, but instead it opens a new blank tab. For the life of me, I can't figure out why.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, on your main.js line 53 you have

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if(!a.test(this.href)) {
       $(this).click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
           window.open(this.href, '_blank');
       });
   }
});
```

so that prevents collapse toggle

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice that someone had added that to make all external links open in new tab (which I then turned off because, boy is that annoying).

Comment: I'm actually wanting this to trigger on a specific link within the navbar and having difficulty recalibrating it. Basically it's the help link. I assumed I could replace the insides of the RegExp with `/help/` and have it work, but it doesn't. Suggestions? It makes everything pop out until I remove the `!`, then nothing pops out. I feel so silly not knowing the answer to this.